# How to initialise register unsigned long in c language

Tags: c

```
unsigned long start, stop;
register unsigned long sp asm ("sp");

start = sp;
```

This line of code states- declaring variable `sp` without initializer.

Comment: Your code as posted works fine in my GCc (4.9.1).  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc 4.4.7 version of GCC (Red hat 4.4.7-4)

Comment: I tested using GCC 4.4.3 and it still compiles without complaint.  Perhaps the error is in code you haven't shown us?  Try compiling only the code you've shown, inside `main()` with nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different architectures use different registers for the stack pointer.  Here is an example (linux+elf) _start function to demonstrate:

```
//unfortunately gcc has no builtin for stack pointer, so we use assembly 
#ifdef __x86_64__ || defined __i386__ 
   #define STACK_POINTER "esp" 
#elif defined __aarch64__ 
   #define STACK_POINTER "x13" 
#elif defined __arm__ 
   #define  STACK_POINTER "r13" 
#endif 
char **environ;
void exit(int);
int main(); 
void _start(void){ 
   register long *sp __asm__( STACK_POINTER ); 
//if you don't use argc, argv or envp/environ,  you can just remove them 
   long argc = *sp; 
   char **argv = (char **)(sp + 1); 
   environ = (char **)(sp + argc + 1); 
   exit(main(argc, argv, environ) ); 
   __builtin_unreachable(); //or for(;;); to shut up gcc 
}
```